# Maven Dependency plugin throwing Sonatype Error

Tags: maven-plugin, maven-dependency-check-plugin

We implemented Dependency-check-maven and this was working fine up till now. But suddenly getting this error now,

[WARNING] An error occurred while analyzing 'oldui/includes/ckeditor/lang/no.js' (Sonatype OSS Index Analyzer).

Not sure where this is originating from?

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is due to https://ossindex.sonatype.org/ certificate is expired on 25th May. When you go to that website, you can see that you get the SSL error.